# How can I hide a div with cookies?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I want to hide a div by pressing a submit button which will add to the client a cookie.
I have tried many ways but till the moment I haven't figured out how can I do it.
Here is my JavaScript & HTML to try.
HTML code + CSS:

```
<div class="postulacion" id="formulario">

    <span class="s_no foca">¿Estás interesado?</span>
    <span class="s_n"> ¡Rellene el siguiente formulario!</span>

    <div class="formulario">
        <span class="recuerde">   <i class="fas fa-lock"></i> Recuerde que toda su información se encuentra encriptada.      </span>
```

CSS Code:

```
.formulario.hidden{
   display: none !important;
}
```

JavaScript code:

```
$.cookie('_dro', 'the_value');

// Create expiring cookie, 7 days from then:
$.cookie('_dro', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });

// Read a cookie
$.cookie('_dro'); // => 'the_value'
$.cookie('not_existing'); // => null



$("#form_send").click(
    $.cookie('_dro', 'the_value', { expires: 7 }));



if (document.cookie.indexOf('_dro') > -1) {
    
        $('.formulario').addClass('hidden');
    
}
else {
    
        $('.formulario').removeClass('hidden');

    
}
```

Comment: You do not need the `function` declarations within the `if... else`. just the jquery to show hide the `div`

Comment: Like @ClydeLobo said: You're currently declaring a function but never call them. Remove the function declaration and it should work.

Comment: I have removed it but still doesn't working, also I have edited the question without the functions. @ClydeLobo